# Отсутствие заголовка в карточке товара. Серый цвет заголовка

Tags: php, css, битрикс

Есть компонент, выводящий разделы, подразделы каталога и элементы разделов каталога

`C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\catalog_goods\index.php`

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Каталог для поисковиков");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Каталог");
?>
    <section>
        <div class="my_white_bg">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <div class="title">
                    <?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
                <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news", 
    "catalog", 
    array(
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ACTION",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "FILE_404" => "",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "10",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog_goods",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ACTION",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Каталог товаров",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/catalog_goods/",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SHOW_404" => "Y",
        "SORT_BY1" => "PROPERTY_PRICE",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
        "USE_FILTER" => "N",
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
        "USE_RATING" => "N",
        "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
        "USE_RSS" => "N",
        "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
        "USE_SHARE" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "catalog",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "news" => "",
            "section" => "#SECTION_CODE#/",
            "detail" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        )
    ),
    false
);?>        
        <!--    
            </div>
        </div> -->
    </section>

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

`C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\catalog\news.php`

`C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\catalog\section.php`

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<?
    if (CModule::IncludeModule('iblock')) {
        $arSection=CIBlockSection::GetList(['LEFT_MARGIN' => 'ASC'], ['IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ACTIVE' => 'Y', 'CODE' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_CODE']])->fetch();
        $dbS=CIBlockSection::GetList(['LEFT_MARGIN' => 'ASC'], ['IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ACTIVE' => 'Y', 'SECTION_ID' => $arSection['ID']]);
        $countS=$dbS->SelectedRowsCount();  
    }
?>


<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section.list",
    "catalog",
    Array(
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => $countS ? "Y" : "N",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS_FILTER" => "CNT_ACTIVE",
        "CUSTOM_SECTION_SORT" => ["ID" => "ASC"],
        "FILTER_NAME" => "sectionsFilter",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
        "SECTION_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
        "TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
        "VIEW_MODE" => "TILE"       
    ),
    $component
);?>


<?if (!$countS):?>

<div class="catalog_list_page">
    <div class="standart_width">

        <div class="catalog_banner">
            <a href=""><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/catalog_banner.png" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content clear_after">
            <div class="content_l">
                <div class="filter_bl">
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                        "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter",
                        "catalog",
                        Array(
                            "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
                            "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
                            "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
                            "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
                            "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "Y",
                            "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
                            "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "vertical",
                            "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
                            "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
                            "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
                            "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
                            "POPUP_POSITION" => "left",
                            "PREFILTER_NAME" => "smartPreFilter",
                            "PRICE_CODE" => array(),
                            "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
                            "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
                            "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
                            "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
                            "SECTION_TITLE" => "-",
                            "SEF_MODE" => "N",
                            "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
                            "XML_EXPORT" => "N"
                        ),
                        $component
                    );?>                
                    <!--<img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/filter.png" alt=""/>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content_c">
                <div class="sorting_bl">
                    <span>Сортировать:</span>
                    <?
                    if ($_GET['by']) {
                        $by = $_GET['by'];
                        setcookie('by', $by, time() + (60*60*24*60), '/');
                    }
                    elseif ($_COOKIE['by']) {
                        $by = $_COOKIE['by'];
                    }
                    else {
                        $by = $arParams["SORT_BY1"];
                    }
                        
                    if ($_GET['sort']) {
                        $sort = $_GET['sort'];
                        setcookie('sort', $sort, time() + (60*60*24*60), '/');  
                    }
                    elseif ($_COOKIE['sort']) {
                        $sort = $_COOKIE['sort'];
                    }   
                    else {
                        $sort = $arParams["SORT_ORDER1"];
                    }

                    $arSort = [
                        'PROPERTY_PRICE' => 'По цене',
                        'PROPERTY_RATING' => 'По рейтингу',
                        'ID' => 'По новизне',
                    ];

                    foreach ($arSort as $k=>$v) {
                        $sort_new='ASC';
                        $class = '';
                        if ($by == $k) {
                            $sort_new = ($sort == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
                            $class = 'active ';
                            $class .= ($sort_new == 'ASC') ? 'max' : 'min';
                        }
                        elseif ($k == 'PROPERTY_RATING' || $k == 'ID') {
                            $sort_new = 'DESC';
                        }
                        
                        $url = $APPLICATION -> GetCurPageParam('by='.$k.'&sort='.$sort_new, ['by', 'sort']);
                        ?><a class="sorting_el <?=$class?>" href="<?=$url?>"><i></i><?=$v?></a><?
                    }
                    ?>      
                    <?/*
                    <a class="sorting_el active min" href=""><i></i>По цене</a>
                    <a class="sorting_el active max" href=""><i></i>По рейтингу</a>
                    <a class="sorting_el" href=""><i></i>По новизне</a>
                    */?>
                </div>


<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "cataloginsection",
    Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "NEWS_COUNT" => $arParams["NEWS_COUNT"],
        "SORT_BY1" => $by,
        "SORT_ORDER1" => $sort,
        "SORT_BY2" => $arParams["SORT_BY2"],
        "SORT_ORDER2" => $arParams["SORT_ORDER2"],
        "FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_FIELD_CODE"],
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_PROPERTY_CODE"],
        "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
        "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
        "IBLOCK_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"],
        "DISPLAY_PANEL" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PANEL"],
        "SET_TITLE" => $arParams["SET_TITLE"],
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => $arParams["SET_LAST_MODIFIED"],
        "MESSAGE_404" => $arParams["MESSAGE_404"],
        "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
        "SHOW_404" => $arParams["SHOW_404"],
        "FILE_404" => $arParams["FILE_404"],
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => $arParams["INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"],
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"],
        "PAGER_TITLE" => $arParams["PAGER_TITLE"],
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["PAGER_TEMPLATE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALL"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK"],
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => $arParams["PAGER_PARAMS_NAME"],
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"],
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"],
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"],
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => $arParams["PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN"],
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => $arParams["LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT"],
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["USE_PERMISSIONS"],
        "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["GROUP_PERMISSIONS"],
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => $arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"],
        "CHECK_DATES" => $arParams["CHECK_DATES"],
        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],        
    ),
    $component
);?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?endif;?>
```

Есть также детальная карточка товара - `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\catalog\bitrix\news.detail\.default\template.php`

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<?
$arProps=$arResult['PROPERTIES'];
?>
    <section>
        <div class="catalog_detail_bl">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <div class="detail_info_bl clear_after">
                    <div class="detail_info_l">
                        <h1>Телевизор <?=$arResult["NAME"]?></h1>
                        <div class="det_star_artic_bl">
                            <div class="cat_el_star">
                                <?for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++):?>
                                    <?if($arProps['RATING']['VALUE']>=$i):?>
                                        <img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                                    <?else:?>
                                        <img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/star_gray.png" alt=""/>
                                    <?endif;?>
                                <?endfor;?>
                            
                                <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                                <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                                <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                                <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                                <img src="./img/star_gray.png" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cat_articul"><?=$arProps['ARTICUL']['VALUE']?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="det_gallery clear_after">
                            <div class="cat_el_status">
                                <?if ($arProps['ACTION']['VALUE']=='Y'):?>
                                    <div class="red">акция</div>
                                <?endif;?>  
                                <?if ($arProps['NEW']['VALUE']=='Y'):?>                             
                                    <div class="green">новинка</div>
                                <?endif;?>
                                <?if ($arProps['HIT']['VALUE']=='Y'):?>
                                    <div class="blue">хит</div>
                                <?endif;?>
                            </div>
                            <?if ($arProps['MORE_PHOTO']['VALUE']):?>
                                <div class="detail_gallery_bl">
                                    <div class="det_slider_bl">
                                        <ul class="det_slider not_style">
                                            <?foreach ($arProps['MORE_PHOTO']['VALUE'] as $i=>$val):?>
                                                <?$path=CFile::GetPath($val);?>
                                                <li><a href="<?=$path?>" data-fancybox="images"><img src="<?=$path?>" alt=""/></a></li>
                                            <?endforeach;?> 
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="det_pager_bl">
                                        <div class="det_pager" id="det_pager">
                                            <?foreach ($arProps['MORE_PHOTO']['VALUE'] as $i=>$val):?>
                                                <?$path=CFile::GetPath($val);?>                                     
                                                <a data-slide-index="0" href="<?=$path?>"><img src="<?=$path?>" alt=""/></a>
                                            <?endforeach;?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?endif;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail_info">
                        <div class="det_price_status_bl">
                            <div class="det_price_bl">
                                <div class="det_price">36 000 р.</div>
                                <div class="cat_old_price">
                                    <div class="price">39 999 р.</div>
                                    <div class="sale">-10%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="favor_bt active" href="">В избранное</a>
                            <div class="det_status_bl">
                                <div class="det_status_el green">В наличии</div>
                                <div class="det_status_el red">Осталось мало</div>
                                <div class="det_status_el blue">Бесплатная доставка</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cat_about_detail_bl section">
            <div class="det_tabs_bl">
                <div class="standart_width">
                    <ul class="tabs det_tabs not_style">
                        <li class="current">Обзор</li>
                        <li>Характеристики</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="standart_width">
                <div class="box det_box" style="display:block;">
                    <div class="double_det_box clear_after">
                        <div class="about_produce_bl">
                            <div class="about_produce_el">
                                <div class="about_produce_tit">Первый плюс</div>
                                <div class="about_produce_txt clear_after">
                                    <img align="left" src="./img/no_photo.png" alt=""/>
                                    <p>И нет сомнений, что сторонники тоталитаризма в науке освещают чрезвычайно интересные особенности картины в целом, однако конкретные выводы, разумеется, рассмотрены исключительно в разрезе маркетинговых и финансовых предпосылок. Таким образом, синтетическое тестирование способствует подготовке и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="about_produce_el">
                                <div class="about_produce_tit">Второй плюс</div>
                                <div class="about_produce_txt clear_after">
                                    <img align="right" src="./img/no_photo.png" alt=""/>
                                    <p>Имеется спорная точка зрения, гласящая примерно следующее: активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира разоблачены! <br/>Равным образом, повышение уровня гражданского сознания, в своем классическом представлении, допускает внедрение поэтапного и последовательного развития общества. Многие известные личности и по сей день остаются уделом либералов, которые жаждут быть заблокированы в рамках своих собственных рациональных ограничений.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="about_produce_el">
                                <div class="about_produce_tit">Третий плюс</div>
                                <div class="about_produce_txt clear_after">
                                    <img align="left" src="./img/no_photo.png" alt=""/>
                                    <p>Перспективное планирование создает предпосылки для экономической целесообразности принимаемых решений. Есть над чем задуматься: сторонники тоталитаризма в науке формируют глобальную экономическую сеть и при этом - объявлены нарушающими общечеловеческие нормы этики и морали.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="about_option_bl">
                            <div class="option_list">
                                <div class="option_tit">Экран</div>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>Диагональ</li>
                                    <li>22" (55.9 см)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>Технология</li>
                                    <li>LED</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>Full HD</li>
                                    <li>Есть</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>Разрешение</li>
                                    <li>1920x1080 Пикс</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="option_list">
                                <div class="option_tit">Функции</div>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>Smart TV</li>
                                    <li>Есть</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="option_list">
                                <div class="option_tit">Интерфейсы</div>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>HDMI3</li>
                                    <li>2</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>Кол-во разъемов USB2</li>
                                    <li>2</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                    <li>Wi-Fi</li>
                                    <li>Есть</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box det_box">
                    <div class="all_option_box clear_after">
                        <div class="title">Основные характеристики телевизора</div>
                        <div class="option_list">
                            <div class="option_tit">Экран</div>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Производитель</li>
                                <li>LG</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Диагональ</li>
                                <li>22" (55.9 см)</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Технология</li>
                                <li>LED</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Тип светодиодной подсветки</li>
                                <li>Edge LED</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Full HD</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Разрешение</li>
                                <li>1920x1080 Пикс</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Прогрессивная развертка</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option_list">
                            <div class="option_tit">Функции</div>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Smart TV</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Таймер выключения</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Таймер включения</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Часы</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Русифицированное меню</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Картинка в картинке (PIP)</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="option_el not_style">
                                <li>Телетекст</li>
                                <li>Есть</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gray_bg">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <div class="title">Другие товары</div>
                <div class="catalog_list">
                    <div class="catalog_el">
                        <div class="cat_el_img">
                            <a href=""><img src="./img/produce1.png" alt=""/></a>
                            <div class="cat_el_status">
                                <div class="red">акция</div>
                                <div class="green">новинка</div>
                                <div class="blue">хит</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_star">
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_gray.png" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_name">
                            <div class="cat_el_tit"><a href="">Стиральная машина  QuickDrive WW6850N</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_price">
                            <div class="cat_el_price_t_c">
                                <div class="cat_old_price">
                                    <div class="price">39 999 р.</div>
                                    <div class="sale">-10%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cat_price">36 000 р.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="favor_bt" href="">В избранное</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="catalog_el">
                        <div class="cat_el_img">
                            <a href=""><img src="./img/produce1.png" alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_star">
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_gray.png" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_name">
                            <div class="cat_el_tit"><a href="">Стиральная машина  QuickDrive WW6850N</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_price">
                            <div class="cat_el_price_t_c">
                                <div class="cat_old_price">
                                    <div class="price">39 999 р.</div>
                                    <div class="sale">-10%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cat_price">36 000 р.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="favor_bt active" href="">В избранное</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="catalog_el">
                        <div class="cat_el_img">
                            <a href=""><img src="./img/produce1.png" alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_star">
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_gray.png" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_name">
                            <div class="cat_el_tit"><a href="">Стиральная машина  QuickDrive WW6850N</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_price">
                            <div class="cat_el_price_t_c">
                                <div class="cat_old_price">
                                    <div class="price">39 999 р.</div>
                                    <div class="sale">-10%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cat_price">36 000 р.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="favor_bt" href="">В избранное</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="catalog_el">
                        <div class="cat_el_img">
                            <a href=""><img src="./img/produce1.png" alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_star">
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_orange.png" alt=""/>
                            <img src="./img/star_gray.png" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_name">
                            <div class="cat_el_tit"><a href="">Стиральная машина  QuickDrive WW6850N</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cat_el_price">
                            <div class="cat_el_price_t_c">
                                <div class="cat_old_price">
                                    <div class="price">39 999 р.</div>
                                    <div class="sale">-10%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cat_price">36 000 р.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="favor_bt" href="">В избранное</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

1. В результате на детальной карточки товара отображается заголовок с `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\catalog_goods\index.php`

   ```
    <div class="my_white_bg">
        <div class="standart_width">
            <div class="title">
                <?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

Детальная карточка товара имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а должно быть как на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы заголовок Каталог не выводился на детальной карточке товара, а в разделах и подразделах выводился (файлы news.php и section.php)?

2. Страница section.php имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но должно быть как на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно заголовок Телевизоры должен быть серого цвета (а у меня белого). Привожу файл со стилями

```css
.gray_bg {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 55px 0 60px;
}

/* line 764, ../sass/screen.scss */
.white_bg {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px 0 60px;
}

.my_white_bg {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0 0px;
}

/* line 768, ../sass/screen.scss */
section .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
/* line 776, ../sass/screen.scss */
section .title:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0070c9;
}
```

Как добиться того, чтобы на Главная>Каталог>Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио>Телевизоры заголовок был серым, а на разделах и подразделах заголовки были белыми?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы заголовок не отображался на детальной странице, нужно этот кусок убрать из index.php и перенести в шаблон catalog компонента bitrix:catalog.section.list.
2. По стилям нужно смотреть в браузере в инструментах разработчика, какие правила работают для данного объекта, в каком порядке и пр. Возможно, имеется какое-то правило, перебивающее ваше.

Comment: раздел Телевизоры находится на предпоследнем уровне. Как сделать так, чтобы для всех разделов предпоследнего уровня заголовок раздела выводился на сером фоне?

Comment: как я понимаю необходимо сравнить $arResult['SECTION']['DEPTH_LEVEL'] внутри шаблона catalog компонента catalog.section.list со значением глубины компонента (инфоблока). Как получить глубину компонента (инфоблока)?